# How can a system like Tesla’s AutoPilot keep up with constant changing requests for multiple process?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, process, multiprocessing, multitasking

As a software developer, I am trying to understand how a system could possibly work as fast and efficiently enough and operate with consistanly and flawlessly with such precision for all the ongoing actions it needs to account for in a system such as a Tesla AutoPilot (self driving car system)...

In a car driving driving 65 MPH, if a deer runs out in front of the car, it immediately makes adjustments to protect the vehicle from a crash - while having to keep up with all the other sensors requests constantly firing off at the same time for possible actions on a micro-milllisecond, without skipping a beat.

How is all of that accomplished sysinctly? And have processing reporting back to it so quickly that it almost intentaniously is able to respond (without getting backed up with requests)?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but as written I don't think it can be given a definitive, factual answer without betraying Tesla trade secrets. :-) Though I could speculate here and guess that the required reaction time is probably closer to the order of milliseconds, giving plenty of time for the computer to do its thing.

Comment: `[ms]` is a long time for nowadays MCU and DSP HW... Using interrupts can speed up control code a lot that is why it is a major condition for RT OS support... For comparison I have some implementations where I react in `[us]` ... So you need to take that into mind when grasping such concepts... as MCU/DSP programming is very different from PC ...

Comment: I voted to close this question as too broad, but I could have also voted to close it as unclear. What does "sysinctly" mean?

Comment: Robin -  I understand there appears to be a misspelling in the word, however I don’t think it necessarily quantifies it being an invalid question. You should be able to use context clues around the other terminology in the question to determine the direction of the question. Alternatively, it is also a pretty straight forward question, if you are farmilar with the topic, and was answered quite well by the answered individual.  If you feel that the question needs to be “down voted”..., please by all means down vote the question.

Comment: Spektre, great points. I appreciate the details. I didn’t consider the side of it that is using micro controllers. That is great info, and I will start looking into the concepts from that side of it. I really appreciate your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: cars usually use a network of MCUs ... so I guess Tesla is no different ... usually each sensor or component is handled by a single MCU ... for harder stuff like LIDAR or even Computer vision are usually used DSPs which are much more effective for such tasks in comparison to RISC/CISC CPU/MCU ... when even that is not fast enough then developers are taping to FPGA ... PCs like computers are used usually just for front end and slow tasks like planing overall route, play music etc ... There are also neural network chips which can be used for "fast" classifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Tesla code, but I have read other real time code and analysed time slips in it. One basic idea is that if you check something every millisecond you will always respond to change within a millisecond. The simplest possible real time system has a "cyclic executive" built around a repeating schedule that tells it what to do when, worked out so that in all possible cases everything that has to be dealt with is dealt with within its deadline. Traditionally you are worrying about cpu time here, but not necessarily. The system I looked at was most affected by the schedule for a serial bus called a 1553 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-1553)- there almost wasn't enough time to get everything transmitted and received on time.

This is a bit too simple because it doesn't cope with rare events which have to be dealt with really quickly, such as response to interrupts. Clever schemes for interrupt handling don't have as much of an advantage as you would expect, because there is often a rare worst case that makes the clever scheme underperform a cyclic executive and real time code has to work in the worst case, but in practice you do need something with interrupt handlers and high priority processes that must be run on demand and with low priority processes that can be ignored when other stuff needs to make deadlines but will be run otherwise. There are various schemes and methodologies for arguing that these more complex systems will always make their deadlines. One of the best known ones is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling.

An open source real time operating system that has seen real life use is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTEMS.

Comment: mcdowella, would it be safe to saw that these type of systems are primarily dealing with low level programming normally dealing directly with hardware level operations/interactions, or could these type of operations be done in Java or C# also?  This is extremely interesting and deals with what seems like a totally different side of programming than I have ever dealt with. Really cool stuff, great response.

Comment: One of the main RTEMS documents is the C User's Guide. If you do a websearch you can also find documentation on how to use Ada with the older "classic" API. A problem with garbage collected languages like Java and C# is that it is not easy to guarantee that the system will not take time out for a garbage collection at a time that causes it to miss a deadline. Even when writing C real time systems people usually design at least the critical real time parts of the code to do all of their memory allocation at startup. This gets tricky if you want to supply a GUI.